# Timer *args, **kwargs in while gets null after first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I've done a repeating timer that doesn't work, the first iteration works but then it says args and kwargs is NoneType even though it worked the first time:

```
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The timer.py:

```
from threading import Timer

class repeat_timer(Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            try:
                self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print("______EXCEPTION IN TIMER_______")
                print(e)
```

This is how i call it:

```
from timer import repeat_timer

timer = repeat_timer(delay, process_multiple_files(filter_json_path))
timer.run()
```

The `delay` is just an int with amount of seconds between each run.
`process_multiple_files(filter_json_path)` is a function to check files and upload to a db. `filter_json_path` is a string with a path to a json file

I dont know where to start since it works perfect the first time but not the second time?

To clarify the timer works and it tries to run the code within each X seconds of `delay`
The problem is when `self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)` is run and gives the exception `'NoneType' object is not callable` the second time of the ireation, so the first run is all fine and dandy but after that it runs but gets an exception as said above.

Comment: you need to create a new timer every time, I don't think they are reusable

Comment: But the timer works, it's the calling of the process_multiple_files() that seems to be the problem?
It does try to call it every x seconds i put in to delay, but it says ```'NoneType' object is not callable``` when trying to run the ```self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)```

Comment: what does `process_multiple_files(filter_json_path)` return? `None`?  If `process_multiple_files` is the function you want to call you need to pass just that as the `function` and the call args after it, like `repeat_timer(delay, process_multiple_files, filter_json_path)`

Comment: Yes ofcourse @Anentropic this was my problem, forgot that in python function() gives the return of the function, it works like a charm now! you can put that in a post instead so i can mark it the solution if you want? Thank you so much =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it like this:

```py
from timer import repeat_timer

timer = repeat_timer(delay, process_multiple_files, filter_json_path)
timer.run()
```

`process_multiple_files` is the function you want the timer to call, and `filter_json_path` is the arg it should pass when in makes the call

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects

> `class threading.Timer(interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None)`
> Create a timer that will run *function* with arguments *args* and keyword arguments *kwargs*, after *interval* seconds have passed. If args is `None` (the default) then an empty list will be used. If kwargs is `None` (the default) then an empty dict will be used.